# How to get the newly inserted worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a pivottable and in column C there is field for which I am showing details for each record using this

```
For i=7 to 10
   DATA.Range("C" & i).ShowDetail = True
   Set wN = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Next i
```

Now it works fine but the problem is  `Set wN = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` assigns the `wN` the first worksheet but  `DATA.Range("C" & i).ShowDetail = True` sometimes inserts the new worksheet which has the details at 1st or 2nd position. Now I want to know which  was the new worksheet which was inserted and assign `wN` to it.

Do I have to make an array or list which keeps record of existing worksheets and then check which is the new one everytime? or there is an easy way to determine which is the newest worksheet in an workbook irrespective of the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `Activesheet`.  `ShowDetail` creates the new sheet and activates it - so `Set wn=ActiveSheet` should work.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables(1)
        For Each c In .DataBodyRange.Resize(, 1)
            c.ShowDetail = True
            Set wrkSht = ActiveSheet
            Debug.Print wrkSht.Name
        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

This link to Jon Peltiers page on Pivot Tables should be a massive help... https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: LOL didn't think of that :) Thanks a lot but that dp is crazy. Is it random pic or there is any reference to it?

Comment: DP?  Displaced Person? Drunken Peasants (that's actually a thing... https://www.reddit.com/r/OfficialDP/)?  Ok.... not searching google anymore, was getting some definitely _Not Safe For Work_ results.

Comment: DP = Display Pic aka Profile Picture

Comment: Ah, right. No, that's me getting my throat cut about 10 years ago at Wimpole Hall. Just a flesh wound though :)

Answer (score 0):

The code shown does not add a worksheet, it sets wN to whatever sheet has index 1 (The second sheet created).

Try `wN.Name = "C"& i & " field"` to help figure out when each sheet is being created.

Comment: `DATA.Range("C" & i).ShowDetail = True` this code adds a worksheet provided that range has a pivottable on it

Comment: Regardless, you will see that you are not referring to the latest sheet created with `Worksheets(1)`. You need to do what Vityata does and get the last indexed sheet to use the most current. ActiveSheet might also accomplish this, but Im not overly familiar with pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new Workbook. Then run this code a few times:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wsNew = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Debug.Print wsNew.Name

End Sub
```

You would see, that `wsNew` is always the last one added. Thus with `Worksheetes(Worksheets.Count)` you may access it.

**Edit:**
If you want to know the name of the last added Worksheet, without adding `After:`, then use collection to remember all the worksheets you had before and simply compare them with the new collection. Run this code a few times:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wsCollection    As New Collection
    Dim lngCounter      As Long
    Dim strName         As String
    Dim blnNameFound    As Boolean
    Dim ws              As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        wsCollection.Add ws.Name
    Next ws

    Worksheets.Add

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        blnNameFound = False
        For lngCounter = 1 To wsCollection.Count
            If wsCollection.Item(lngCounter) = ws.Name Then
                blnNameFound = True
            End If
        Next lngCounter

        If Not blnNameFound Then Debug.Print ws.Name

    Next ws

End Sub
```

The complexity is O².

Comment: That's easy to access because you have `Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` but `DATA.Range("C" & i).ShowDetail = True` can't control where the worksheet is inserted before or after so it's hard to tell which is the newest worksheet.

Comment: Is there any setting or control which will always insert new worksheets after After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) when using DATA.Range("C" & i).ShowDetail = True ?

Comment: Thanks for your help it seems all I needed was to set wn to activesheet :)

Comment: @vicky - that's an option as well. But sometimes you do not need activesheets.